# Generator of sigma field that is generated by an intersection of a decreasing sequence of generators.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set and let $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be 
sequence of intersection stable systems over $\Omega$ (i.e. $E_n$ is a set consisting of subsets of $\Omega$ satisfying $A, B\in E_n$ $\Longrightarrow$ $A \cap B\in E_n$)  such that $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Is it true that 
$$
\sigma\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_n\right)= \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sigma(E_n),
$$
where $\sigma(E)$ denotes the smallest $\sigma$-field over $\Omega$ that contains $E$?

Comment: Are you merely asking if it is true?  So two or three letters in an answer: "yes"/"no"?  What are your thoughts on the matter?  Is there some reason you're having trouble, and if so, please describe where you are stuck in an edit to your draft above.

Comment: Off the record: Hallo @amWhy, that is some time ago. Nice to see you back!

Comment: Thanks, @drhab !

Comment: @amWhy: Obviously, the lhs is contained in the rhs. The converse direction could be problematic and I have no counter-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is wrong: We consider a Brownian Motion $B= (B_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ defined on the space $\Omega = C([0,1])$ of continuous functions from [0,1] to $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the canonical filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$. 
It is a known fact that the filtration 
is not right continuous, i.e one has $\mathcal{F}_0 \not= \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{1/n}$.

This can now be used to give an counter-example to the above statement. 
For $t\in [0,1]$ we denote by $E_t$ the system of all sets
$\{B_{t_1}\in A_1, \dots, B_{t_n}\in A_n\}$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $0\le t_1\le \dots \le t_n\le t$ and $A_1,\dots, A_n$ are arbitrary Borel-sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Then, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} E_{1/n} = E_0$ and 
$\sigma(E_0) = \mathcal{F}_0 \not= \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{F}_{1/n} = \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sigma(E_{1/n})$